# Run when you can

Tags: ruby, performance, optimization, sinatra

In my sinatra web application, I have a route:

```
get "/" do
    temp = MyClass.new("hello",1)
    redirect "/home"
end
```

Where `MyClass` is:

```
class MyClass
    @instancesArray = []
    def initialize(string,id)
        @string = string
        @id = id
        @instancesArray[id] = this
    end
    def run(id)
        puts @instancesArray[id].string
    end
end
```

At some point I would want to run `MyClass.run(1)`, but I wouldn't want it to execute immediately because that would slow down the servers response to some clients. I would want the server to wait to run `MyClass.run(temp)` until there was some time with a lighter load. How could I tell it to wait until there is an empty/light load, then run `MyClass.run(temp)`? Can I do that?

**Addendum**

Here is some sample code for what I would want to do:

```
$var = 0

get "/" do
    $var = $var+1 # each time a request is recieved, it incriments
end
```

After that I would have a loop that would count requests/minute (so after a minute it would reset `$var` to 0, and if `$var` was less than some number, then it would run tasks util the load increased.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew mentioned (correctly—not sure why he was voted down), Sinatra [stops](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L260) processing a route when it sees a `redirect`, so any subsequent statements will never execute. As you stated, you don't want to put those statements *before* the `redirect` because that will block the request until they complete. You could potentially send the redirect status and header to the client without using the `redirect` method and *then* call `MyClass#run`. This will have the desired effect (from the client's perspective), but the server process (or thread) will block until it completes. This is undesirable because that process (or thread) will not be able to serve any new requests until it unblocks.

You could fork a new process (or spawn a new thread) to handle this background task asynchronously from the main process associated with the request. Unfortunately, this approach has the potential to get messy. You would have to code around different situations like the background task failing, or the `fork`/`spawn` failing, or the main request process not ending if it owns a running thread or other process. (Disclaimer: I don't really know enough about IPC in Ruby and Rack under different application servers to understand all of the different scenarios, but I'm confident that here there be dragons.)

The most common solution pattern for this type of problem is to push the task into some kind of work queue to be serviced later by another process. Pushing a task onto the queue is ideally a very quick operation, and won't block the main process for more than a few milliseconds. This introduces a few new challenges (where is the queue? how is the task described so that it can be facilitated at a later time without any context? how do we maintain the worker processes?) but fortunately a lot of the leg work has already been done by other people. :-)

There is the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem, which seems to provide a nice all-in-one solution. Unfortunately, it's mostly geared towards Rails and ActiveRecord, and the efforts people have made in the past to make it work with Sinatra look to be unmaintained. The contemporary, framework-agnostic solutions are [Resque](http://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque) and [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org). It might take some effort to get up and running with either option, but it would be well worth it if you have several "run when you can" type functions in your application.

Comment: I had actually already seen the work queue solution, and was looking if there was something better, because the work queue solution will still slow down the next request because the server will be busy and have less resources available. But +1 for the great detailed answer! I will certainly look into that gem as it seems to be the most promising solution for me.

Comment: But what I am also looking for is a way to run things when the server traffic lessens. So I would need something that would just track the traffic, and when the load on the server is light, it would execute the tasks.

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to run the background process(es) with `nice`, which "hints" to the kernel to run the command with a lower priority.

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass.run(temp)` is never actually executing. In your current request to `/` path you instantiate a new instance of `MyClass` then it will immediately do a `get` request to `/home`. I'm not entirely sure what the question is though. If you want something to execute after the redirect, that functionality needs to exist within the `/home` route.

```
get '/home' do
  # some code like MyClass.run(some_arg)
end
```

Comment: Opps sorry! Typo! This might have been better as a comment. I have fixed by question now.